# how do i cache images in nativescript angular

Tags: nativescript

I created an app and it does work great but images load every time I scroll up and down, I looked it in google and found [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-js/blob/141b27be97d30c83e86dd042fe17bb8d4d7c3e32/app/ui-category/image-cache/basics/basics-page.js#L39), the problem is I use angular, there is no such thing as `viewModel` in my angular version, how do I apply cache image into template?

Answer (score 2):

```
You can try this code. It is working for me.

.ts code

 import imageCacheModule = require("ui/image-cache");
 import imageSource = require("image-source");
 var cache = new imageCacheModule.Cache();

 private _imageSrc: any;
 private imgSource: any;


    getImageCache(imageURL) {
        cache.placeholder = imageSource.fromResource("res://no-image.png");
        cache.maxRequests = 10;

        cache.enableDownload()
        var images = cache.get(imageURL)
        if(images) {

           return images
        } else {

            cache.push({
                key: imageURL,
                url: imageURL,
                completed: (image: any, key: string) => {
                    if (imageURL === key) {
                        this.imgSource = imageSource.fromNativeSource(images);
                    }
                }
            })

        cache.disableDownload();
    }

HTMl code

<Image  [src]="getImageCache(item.image?.url)" class="item-image"></Image>
```

Comment: How does this work? `else` part doesn't have any `return` statement. And what is that private `imgSource` property? I'm confused.

Comment: In else  'this.imgSource' will update the image. You can add console and check.